# load data into UITableViewCell cell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm totally new to IOS dev and I'm looking for help on what I'm sure is a simple issue. I'm building a test app to learn loops, code, IBoutlets etc and I have create an app that reads in between 1-5 random names into an array, I now want to read those elements into a table that I have on the same screen. If I try and use a WHILE loop then I get an error that it cannot find Return Cell, if I don't use a loop then it prints all elements in every cell.

thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    Table.dataSource=self
}
@IBAction func Buttonpressed (){
    GetMoves()
}

func GetMoves() {
    var i=0
    var ArrayMove:String
    ChosenNumber=Int(Field.text!)
    ArrayMove=" "
    while i < ChosenNumber{
        ArrayMove=Moves[i]
        ChosenMoves.append(ArrayMove)
        i+=1
        self.Table.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ChosenMoves.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var movestring=" "
    var i=0
  //  while i<ChosenMoves.count{
        let Cell=Table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        i=indexPath.row
        movestring=" "
        movestring=ChosenMoves[i]
        Cell.CellLabel.text=movestring
        i+=1
    
        return Cell
    
    }
```

I want each array element appears on an individual row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing mistake while dequeuing cell. You have used `Table` where as you need to use `tableView`. I think there is no need of declaring variable `i` and similarly no need to increment it. Here is the updated method .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell=Table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    Cell.CellLabel.text = ChosenMoves[indexPath.row]
    return Cell
}
```

I removed extra variables. One more point, above method by default gets called on every count. You don't need to use loop for it. Furthermore, I would suggest to go through `swift language guide` or `100 days of swift` tutorial for better understanding.

Comment: amazing thank you, do you know how I would then refresh it if the button is repressed? reloaddata no longer refreshes

Comment: First of all, there are few mistakes in your code. You need to follow naming convention. If `reloadData()` does not reloads table, it can have following issues.
1. please your UITableView outlet, make sure it is properly set. 
2. ChosenNumber=Int(Field.text!) this might cause crash to your app. what is `Field` here. Try to use if let or guard let to unwrap it. 
3. You don't need to call `reloadData()` inside loop. You can call it once you have got your array set. 

Note: Please make sure all of your outlets are properly set. Following naming convention for whole code.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but it's appending them to the bottom of the table each time, rather than clearing and adding new. For my benefit of learning, how does it know how many times to loop and add from the array? I can't figure that bit out in the code as there's no for or while loop

Comment: Ignore that, I found the array wasn't being cleared, fixed now :) thanks